# Using celery with multiple processing , the notify signal can't be received by waiting thread

Tags: python, django, celery, python-multithreading

When I use celery with multiple processing, the notify signal can't be received by the waiting thread!

but when I run the code with the script, it works normally.

Is the problem caused by celery poor support for multithreading?

Please give me a hint if you can resolve the problem, thank you!

```
# tasks.py

@shared_task(bind=True)
def long_time_def(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tp = ThreadPool(5)
    tp.set_tasks(pv.check_position_effective, list(args))
    res = tp.final_results()
    while len(res) < len(args):
        print(res)
    return 'finished'
```

```
# ../public/tools.py

class ThreadPool:
    def __init__(self, max_thread_num=5):
        self.over = False
        self.results = []

        self.func = None
        self.args_list = None
        self.task_num = 0
        self.max_thread_num = max_thread_num

        self.pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_thread_num)
        self.cond = threading.Condition()

    def set_tasks(self, func, args_list):
        self.task_num = len(args_list)
        self.args_list = args_list
        self.func = func


    def get_result(self, future):
        self.results.append(future.result())
        if len(self.args_list):
            args = self.args_list.pop()
            task = self.pool.submit(self.func, *args)
            task.add_done_callback(self.get_result)
        else:
            print("result：%s"%self.results)
            while self.task_num != len(self.results):
                print(self.results)
                time.sleep(1)
            print('\n', 'finish')
            self.cond.acquire()

            ############ this place ############
            self.cond.notify()
            ############ this place ############

            self.cond.release()
            return

    def _start_tasks(self):
        for i in range(self.max_thread_num):

            if len(self.args_list):
                args = self.args_list.pop()
                task = self.pool.submit(self.func, *args)
                task.add_done_callback(self.get_result)
            else:
                break

    def final_results(self):
        self._start_tasks()
        if self.task_num == len(self.results):
            return self.results
        else:
            # print("main locked")
            # self.cond.acquire()

            ############ this place ############
            print("main waiting")
            self.cond.wait()
            ############ this place ############

            # print("main released")
            # self.cond.release()
            print("main finished")
            return self.results
```

## output

> [2020-04-27 20:53:13,962: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: position.tasks.long_time_def[*****-*****]
>
> [2020-04-27 20:53:13,991: WARNING/MainProcess] main waiting
>
> [2020-04-27 20:53:29,091: WARNING/MainProcess] result：[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>
> [2020-04-27 20:53:29,092: WARNING/MainProcess] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>
> [2020-04-27 20:53:30,145: WARNING/MainProcess] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>
> [2020-04-27 20:53:30,155: WARNING/MainProcess] result：[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>
> [2020-04-27 20:53:30,156: WARNING/MainProcess] finish

Answer (score 0):

Celery uses [Billiard](https://github.com/celery/billiard) for process management, so you have to use Billiard instead of multiprocessing for the time being.